# Centering No Captcha reCaptcha

Tags: css, recaptcha, center

After a few hours of research and trial and error, I was finally able to add the new Google No Capatcha re Capatcha to my form and get it working, but for some reason, it won't center. Any ideas?

```
<!-- reCapatcha -->
<div id="capatcha">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
</div>


#capatcha {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block
}
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I went with:

```
<style>
    /* already defined in bootstrap4 */
    .text-xs-center {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .g-recaptcha {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
<div class="text-xs-center">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer as avoids the fixed values in styles. If used within a bootstrap context then apply `.text-center` to the surrounding column div and then just add the `.g-recaptcha` style to your custom css

Comment: @NevilleDastur just updated the amswer with your idea.

Comment: This ended working fine for me; simple as hell. Thanks ;)
Also you may add the inside of <style> inside a custom css if you have one

Answer (score 43):

This is similar to other answers, but I thought worth sharing.  I don't like hard-coding values, but the width of the No Captcha reCAPTCHA appears to be 304px, so you could use that as your width:

```
<style>
div.g-recaptcha {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 304px;
}
</style>

<!-- reCAPTCHA -->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
```

This should center the reCAPTCHA exactly.

Comment: [this solution below is far better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29836372/124486). For the reason look in the comment by @NevilleDastur (I agree w/ him).

Answer (score 17):

This css works fine for me:

```
.g-recaptcha{
   margin: 15px auto !important;
   width: auto !important;
   height: auto !important;
   text-align: -webkit-center;
   text-align: -moz-center;
   text-align: -o-center;
   text-align: -ms-center;
}
```

Comment: using text-align: -ms-center; was enough for me, thanks

Answer (score 13):

I don't like the idea of hardcoding `304px` in my .scss

The g-recaptcha html is generated as:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" ... >
  <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
    <div>
      <iframe ... ></iframe>
    </div>
    <textarea ... ></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

This horizontally centres the first inner div (which specifies width=304px).

```
<style>
.g-recaptcha > div {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

This CSS style works well for me.

```
.g-recaptcha > div:first-of-type {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit: This answer is pretty much the worst one in the chain. Use some other one please.

Try adding

```
width: 50%;
```

to your css. I looked at another answer and it said that

```
display: block;
```

is for IE.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, width: 100% wasn't doing anything for me but when I tried 50% and it was pretty close to where I wanted it ended up with 75%

Comment: Out of all the answers, this is the worst. Check this one for a [much better idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29836372/124486)

Comment: @EvanCarroll I can't change if my answer is accepted or not. I know it's bad. It was answered 1 1/2 years ago. Now I know better.

Comment: this works but not it is not a responsive solution. will fail on different screens.

Answer (score 4):

What russianmario says does infact work, but instead of hard coding the 304px in you can just use the fit-content.

```
<style>
div.g-recaptcha {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
}
</style>

<!-- reCAPTCHA -->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

this code will be worked.

```html
<div align="center" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your key code"></div>
```

Comment: It's not valid HTML5. align is long deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this style in your page:

```
<style>
   .g-recaptcha>div {margin: 0 auto;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using reCaptcha with Bootstrap you can do the following:

```
<div class="text-center">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{> reCAPTCHA}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
</div>
```

```
.text-center{text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following css worked perfectly for me by wrapping the reCaptcha in a div and adjusting the padding-left value until I got the reCaptcha centered.

```
<style>
.g-recaptcha div { margin: 0 auto; padding-left: 70px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4 you can easily do this by creating a div containing with a class of text-center. Then add to the g-recaptcha class tag d-inline-block

```
<div class="text-center"><div class="g-recaptcha d-inline-block" data-sitekey="your-site-key-here"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for primefaces you can do:

```
<div class="text-center captcha">
     <p:captcha label="Captcha" size="100%"/>
</div>
```

---

```
.captcha>div>div{
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
#capatcha {
margin: 0 auto;
display block;
}
</style>
<!-- reCapatcha -->
<div style="width: 100px; border: solid 1px;"
<div id="capatcha">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="">1234</div>
</div>
</div>
```

tested on blank page works.

Comment: are you actually calling the javascript which mutates the .g-recaptcha class? This question isn't about g-recaptcha in the abstract. It's about the library google puts out.